# How can I programmatically access Visual Studio 2013's Return Values that appear in the Autos Window?

Tags: visual-studio, vsx, envdte, vsix, vs-extensibility

Visual Studio 2013 has the [capability of showing the return values of every method in the statement that's been stepped over](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/06/27/seeing-function-return-values-in-the-debugger-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx). They appear in the autos window. My question is, how can I programmatically obtain them, using VS-SDK (as IDebugProperty2's) or as EnvDTE.Expression's? Is there an API for this?

I know I can evaluate "$ReturnValue" to get the last return value, but I'd like to obtain all the return values of the method we just stepped over, including their names.

Comment: What?  Assign the return value of the method to a variable.  If you want a history of value assignments, use a property with logging capability instead, or put some logging in the method that captures the value before returning it.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I tagged this question under 'vs-extensibility'. I need this for a Visual Studio extension, not an issue in my own code base.